# Having an issue calculating a negative number minus another number

Tags: java, android

So I've written a calculator and it works for all inputs except when you take a negative nuber and minus another one, it doesn't function.

```
// calculation logic
    public void calculate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < textField.length(); i++) {
            if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '+') {
                result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) + Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
                returnAnswer(decimalFormat.format(result));
            } else if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '-') {
                if (textField.getText().charAt(0) != '-') {
                    result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) - Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
                    returnAnswer(decimalFormat.format(result));
                }
                            // I know I need to write code here but what?
            } else if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '*') {
                result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) * Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
                returnAnswer(decimalFormat.format(result));
            } else if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '÷') {
                result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) / Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
                returnAnswer(decimalFormat.format(result));
            }
        }
        resultDisplayed = true;
    }
```

I've commented where I think the problem arises and needs codes to fix as it doesn't take the case of if there **is** a '-' sign at position [0]. But I'm not sure how to do this as the calculation just crashes the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it like this:

```
else if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '-' && i !=0) {
  result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) - Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
  returnAnswer(decimalFormat.format(result));
}
```

Then it will ignore the - if its the first character, but otherwise continue. Have tried this locally and it appears to work.

Edit: It may be worth doing the same for the + symbol, just in case someone enters '+5*10'

Comment: Cheers, works like a charm! New I was missing something simple. The rest all works fine, the user can't enter anything except a - as the first character. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. The other possibility would then be to start your loop with i=1, then you always ignore the first character when detecting the function.

Comment: I tried that but then it wouldn't pick up the fact that the first number is negative.